# Aligning columns of numbers in a loop

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to replicate a list of conversions from kg to lbs and vice versa. I've found my desired code for output and functionality, but I am missing something to align my values to the right of the column.

Here is my code:

```
import java.text.*;

public class KilosTwoColumn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Kilograms" + "\t" + "Pounds" + "\t" + " | " + "\t" + "Pounds" + "\t" + "Kilograms");

        int count = 0;

        while (count < 100) {
            int kilos = count * 2 + 1;
            int pounds2 = (count + 4) * 5;
            double pounds = kilos * 2.2;
            double kilos2 = pounds2 * .453;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

            //if (count > 1 && count < 98) {
                //System.out.println("...");
                //break;
            //}

            System.out.printf("%-17d %.1f    | %7d        %.2f%n", kilos, pounds, pounds2, kilos2);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am also trying to create a break in the list three rows in and resume the last two.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your request right: you have everything you need already in the printf function for proper alignment. What are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not specifying a width for the float values, just the number of decimal places.....

For example, consider `"%-17d %.1f ..."` which will set the second value to be a float value with 1 decimal place, but no indication of how much space to occupy. By changing that to `"%-17d %12.1f` it will occupy 12 characters, with 1 decimal.

Try something like:

```
public class KilosTwoColumn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.printf("%12s  %12s  |  %7s   %12s\n", "Kilograms", "Pounds", "Pounds", "Kilograms");

        int count = 0;

        while (count < 100) {
            int kilos = count * 2 + 1;
            int pounds2 = (count + 4) * 5;
            double pounds = kilos * 2.2;
            double kilos2 = pounds2 * .453;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

            //if (count > 1 && count < 98) {
                //System.out.println("...");
                //break;
            //}

            System.out.printf("%12d  %12.1f  |  %7d   %12.1f\n", kilos, pounds, pounds2, kilos2);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

For me, the above process outputs:

```
Kilograms        Pounds  |   Pounds      Kilograms
        1           2.2  |       20            9.1
        3           6.6  |       25           11.3
....
      199         437.8  |      515          233.3
```